# Change Data Capture Gap Events with multiple record ids

Tags: streaming-api, change-data-capture

Looking through CDC Gap Events, it appears that new values for the objects aren't included, but we can have multiple records changed in a single gap event.

Is it safe to assume that the values for all of changed fields in each record in that gap event are the same?

i.e. GAP event with 
RECORD_ID1 & RECORD_ID2 changed.
ChangedFields = Description

Can I read the value from RECORD_ID1 and assume RECORD_ID2 will have the same value?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_other_events_gap.htm